# Django Multiple Inlines with Dropdown prefilled

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a Django 1.8.7 application and a Model with an Inline for the field "description" in multiple languages.

The goal is to have none or one inline tops for each language. How can I make sure a language is not filled twice and force one Inline per language and object?

Is it possible to have a Dropdown with the languages in the Inline but not editable and prefilled with one language each. For example lets say I have German and English as languages in my Django settings. I then want for the object one Inline which represents German and one Inline representing English language.

Does anyone have an Idea how to achieve that?

Code Snippets:

models.py:

```
class LocalizedAuthorDetails(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(
        _('language'),
        max_length=64,
        db_index=True,
        choices=get_author_language_choices(),
        default=get_author_language_choices()[0],
    )
    external_author = models.ForeignKey(
        'ExternalAuthor', verbose_name=_('external_author'))
    description = models.TextField(
        _('description'),
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    comment = models.TextField(
        _('comment'),
        blank=True,
        default=''
    )
```

AdminInline:

```
class LocalizedAuthorDetailsBackend(admin.StackedInline):

    model = LocalizedAuthorDetails
    max_num = len(settings.LANGUAGES)
```

AdminForm where Inline is used:

```
class AuthorBackend(BackendModelAdmin, ExternalAuthorAdmin):
    list_display = ('Thumbnail', 'FullName', 'email', 'public')
    inlines = (LocalizedAuthorDetailsBackend, )
```

Comment: Can you show some code examples? Are we talking about admin inlines?

Comment: Done hope these help and yes admin inlines